# Searching hyperparameters for models with group based validation methods in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I would like to perform hyperparamter optimisation for a model I have trained in Scikit-Learn.  I want to first use a random search to get an idea of a good area to search in and then follow it up with a grid search.  The method of validation I need to use is Leave One Group Out (LOGO).

So something to this effect:

```
distributions = {
    "n_estimators": randint(low=1, high=500),
    "criterion": ["squared_error", "absolute_error", "poisson"],
    "max_depth": randint(low=1, high=100)
}

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(
    forest_reg, 
    distributions, 
    cv=LeaveOneGroupOut(), 
    groups=group, 
    scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", 
    return_train_score=True, 
    random_state=42,
    n_jobs=-1,
    n_iter=20
)

random_search.fit(X, y)
```

Neither RandomizedSearchCV or GridSearchCV offer support for LOGO validation with definition of groups.  When I use a method such as cross_val_score() I can send in a chosen cross validation method like so

```
scores = cross_val_score(
    forest_reg, 
    X, 
    y, 
    scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", 
    cv=LeaveOneGroupOut(), 
    groups=group, 
    n_jobs=-1
)
```

Is there a reason that the same is not supported with either of the hyperparameter search methods?  Am I using the API in the wrong way?  Is there a way to achieve what I want using sklearn, without cludging something together myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups should be passed into the `fit()` method when using `LeaveOneGroupOut`.

`RandomizedSearchCV.fit()` documentation specify that the parameter `groups` should be used only in conjunction with a “Group” cv instance such as `GroupKFold` or `LeaveOneGroupOut`.

See example below:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, LeaveOneGroupOut
import numpy as np

params = {
    "n_estimators": [1, 5, 10],
    "max_depth": [2, 5, 10]
}

X, y = make_regression()
groups = np.random.randint(5, size=y.shape)
cv = RandomizedSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor(),
                        params,
                        cv=LeaveOneGroupOut()
)

cv.fit(X, y, groups=groups)
```